# Why cannot I compile the opencv?

Tags: opencv

I'm using Centos 7.2. I tried to compile and install `opencv` using `cmake`.
I run these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv
cd opencv
mkdir -p build
cd build
```

The problem happens when I run the command:

```
cmake -D BUILD_opencv_gpu=OFF -D WITH_EIGEN=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D WITH_1394=OFF -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/ghome/mypath/software/try_opencv/installed ..
```

I have tried many solutions, such as downloading the latest version, compiling with `-D BUILD_opencv_ts=0`. But none of them helps.
I have been stuck in this problem for hours and I cannot solve it. The problem message is as follows:

```
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 48 (408)
-- FP16: Feature disabled
-- Found ZLIB: /lib64/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.7", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing:  JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Found ZLIB: /lib64/libz.so (found version "1.2.7") 
-- Could NOT find PNG (missing:  PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
--   No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Checking for modules 'libavcodec;libavformat;libavutil;libswscale'
--   No package 'libavcodec' found
--   No package 'libavformat' found
--   No package 'libavutil' found
--   No package 'libswscale' found
-- Checking for module 'libavresample'
--   No package 'libavresample' found
-- Checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   No package 'libgphoto2' found
CMake Warning at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:56 (message):
  ICV: Local copy of ICV package has invalid MD5 hash:
  d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e (expected:
  808b791a6eac9ed78d32a7666804320e)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:110 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:243 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:37 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:567 (include)


-- ICV: Downloading ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz...
CMake Error at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:73 (file):
  file DOWNLOAD HASH mismatch

    for file: [/ghome/mypath/software/try_opencv/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/downloads/linux-808b791a6eac9ed78d32a7666804320e/ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz]
      expected hash: [808b791a6eac9ed78d32a7666804320e]
        actual hash: [d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e]
             status: [1;"Unsupported protocol"]

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:110 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:243 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:37 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:567 (include)


CMake Error at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:77 (message):
  ICV: Failed to download ICV package: ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz.
  Status=1;"Unsupported protocol"
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:110 (_icv_downloader)
  cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:243 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:37 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:567 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/ghome/mypath/software/try_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/ghome/mypath/software/try_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Thank you all for helping me!!!

Comment: I think I would try removing and purging the `cmake` package and reinstalling it afresh, followed, if necessary, by recloning the OpenCV github repository

Answer (score 1):

Since the error seems in downloading ippicv, if you don't need it strictly you can simply disable it adding `-D WITH_IPP=OFF` in your cmake configuration line.

A very similar question was asked [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/40425/opencv-build-fails-because-i-cannot-download-icv-on-our-build-farm/).

It could also be that updating CMake might solve the problem. To do so, if you are in a Linux environment, consider [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/595441/359343).

Comment: Sorry your answer does not solve my problem. I just don't know what's wrong with my commands but when I change to another version of opencv, I get it down. I cannot tell whether your answer is correct. But your answer does not solve my problem. But still thank you for your help and I will not add a finger down to your answer.